# JQuery DatePicker not working after first instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I couldn't find anything that seemed to answer why my DatePicker would not work more than once on the same page. Below is the code I'm using, with most of the body content removed for clarity's sake and ease of reading:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load jQuery from Google's CDN -->        
    <!-- Load jQuery UI CSS  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <!-- Load jQuery JS -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <!-- Load jQuery UI Main JS  -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- Load SCRIPT.JS which will create datepicker for input field  -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="runnable.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Pick a Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
    <p>Pick a Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
    <p>Date:<input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
  </body>
```

Can anyone tell me why it's only working for the first instance but not the following 2?

Thanks!

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple instances with an `id` of `datepicker`, and this is invalid HTML. `id` should be a unique field.

If you want to apply to multiple ones, make it a class:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" />
```

and then apply it using the class selector:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

This will solve both the invalid HTML and multiple instances problems.

As a little extra information, the reason it works for only the first instance is because the ID selector in jQuery stops looking in the DOM for elements after it finds the first (and what should be only) match.

Comment: Hot holy moses I don't know how I didn't see the ID duplication on my own. It's not like I've been working in HTML forever (sarcasm). I've applied the class as you suggested and it worked great. Thanks!

Comment: if it solved the problem, don't thank me ... thank the checkmark. ;)

Comment: I'm planning on it, but I can't accept the answer for another couple of minutes.